# Error code: 2008 MySQL client ran out of memory

Tags: mysql

I have a large DB. When I try to retrieve the table using MySQL workbench I get the following error:

```
Error code: 2008 MySQL client ran out of memory
```

One provided solution by MySQL is to use `--quick` option but I work with the workbench. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: There's an outstanding bug in Workbench to cater for this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65728

Comment: I use version 5.2.40 which supposed to be the latest version and does not have the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are using more memory than has been provided to you... try slicing down your memory in a number of chunks.  I also faced this problem in python connection so I used generators and sliced my query in number of chunks ... this will not take your memory.

Try using limit and offset.